# Site title in chat's footer is impossible to read

Tags: bug, chat, site-design

Bottom right corner of chat reads:

[image]

The link is slightly hard to click and impossible to read. Could use a linebreak, obviously.

For reference, Cog Sci's footer link looks like this:

[image]

The header in the Chat main page doesn't look much better either:

[image]